# How to get permission for an application to access Microsoft Graph API using mail?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

As of now, I have created an application that has certain permissions to access Mail Information of certain users in an organization. Till this point, admin from the organization would create the service and provide the credentials.

However, as a plan to scale the application to multiple organizations, I'd like to send a mail to admin to grant access for the permissions and automatically get the credentials.

I'm open to alternative ideas. Any ideas if the above is even feasible?

Comment: Hello, are you trying to make your app multi-tenant? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/single-and-multi-tenant-apps

Comment: Yes, it'd be a multi-tenant app. However, I'd like this process completely automated. Right from creating the app with specific app permissions to the request for admin consent sent via mail or by any alternative means and then getting the client secret. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is quite impossible to automate the complete process creating, and admin still need to approve the permission in Azure AD. What you can do here is ,just create the application and if user tries to access the app but they can't give consent ,they need to trigger a request for admin approval that can be sent by an email .

To allows admin consent request to be sent via email Configure the admin consent workflow , please follow the docs - [Azure AD | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-admin-consent-workflow)

Hope that process will help you .